# "Restrict adding a street view marker to a specific area in a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have decided to start learning Leaflet and JavaScript by creating a road-trip map of my summer in Norway, here is a reproducible sample of my project:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([61.9241, 6.7527], 6);
var streetViewMarker = null; // Variable to keep track of the Street View marker

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var roadTripCoordinates = [
  [59.9139, 10.7522], // Oslo
  [62.2622, 10.7654], // Tynset
  [62.5949, 9.6926], // Oppdal
  [63.0071, 7.2058], // Atlantic Road
  [62.1040, 7.2054] // Geiranger
];

// Function to initialize Slick Carousel for a specific marker
function initSlickCarousel(markerId, images) {
  $(`#${markerId}_carousel`).slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    arrows: true
  });

  // Add images to the carousel
  images.forEach(img => {
    $(`#${markerId}_carousel`).slick('slickAdd', `<div><img src="${img}" alt="Image"></div>`);
  });
}

// Add markers for each destination with additional information and multiple pictures
var destinations = [{
    coordinates: [59.9139, 10.7522],
    name: 'Oslo',
    info: "../07/2023 : Start of the road-trip",
    images: ['https://www.ecologie.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/styles/standard/public/Oslo%2C%20Norvege_AdobeStock_221885853.jpeg?itok=13d8oQbU', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300']
  },
  {
    coordinates: [62.2622, 10.7654],
    name: 'Tynset',
    info: "../07/2023 : Fly-fishing spot 1",
    images: ['https://www.czechnymph.com/data/web/gallery/fisheries/norway/glommahein/Kvennan_Fly_Fishing_20.jpg', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300']
  },
  {
    coordinates: [62.5949, 9.6926],
    name: 'Oppdal',
    info: "../07/2023 : Awesome van spot for the night",
    images: ['https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFRtpLlHWr8j6S2jNStnq6_Z9qBe0jWuFH8Q&usqp=CAU', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300']
  },
  {
    coordinates: [63.0071, 7.2058],
    name: 'Atlantic Road',
    info: "../07/2023 : Fjord fishing",
    images: ['https://images.locationscout.net/2021/04/atlantic-ocean-road-norway.jpg?h=1100&q=83', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300']
  },
  {
    coordinates: [62.1040, 7.2054],
    name: 'Geiranger',
    info: "../07/2023 : Hiking 1",
    images: ['https://www.fjordtours.com/media/10968/nicola_montaldo-instagram-26th-may-2021-0717-utc.jpeg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=1120&height=1120&rnd=133209254300000000&slimmage=True', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300', 'https://via.placeholder.com/300']
  }
];

// Use Leaflet Routing Machine with Mapbox Routing plugin to get and display the route
L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: roadTripCoordinates.map(coord => L.latLng(coord[0], coord[1])),
  router: L.Routing.mapbox('MAP_BOX_KEY'),
  draggableWaypoints: false,
  addWaypoints: false,
  lineOptions: {
    styles: [{
      color: 'brown',
      opacity: 0.7,
      weight: 2
    }]
  }
}).addTo(map);

// Remove the leaflet-routing-container from the DOM
var routingContainer = document.querySelector('.leaflet-routing-container');
if (routingContainer) {
  routingContainer.parentNode.removeChild(routingContainer);
}

destinations.forEach(function(destination) {
  var marker = L.marker(destination.coordinates).addTo(map);
  var markerId = destination.name.replace(' ', '_');

  marker.bindPopup(`
        <b>${destination.name}</b><br>
        ${destination.info}<br>
        <div class="carousel" id="${markerId}_carousel"></div>
    `).on('popupopen', function() {
    // Initialize Slick Carousel when the marker popup is opened
    initSlickCarousel(markerId, destination.images);
  }).openPopup();
});

// Add Street View panorama on map click
map.on('click', function(e) {
  if (streetViewMarker) {
    // Remove the existing Street View marker
    map.removeLayer(streetViewMarker);
  }

  let lat = e.latlng.lat.toPrecision(8);
  let lon = e.latlng.lng.toPrecision(8);
  streetViewMarker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup(`<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=${lat},${lon}&cbp=11,0,0,0,0" target="blank"><b> Cliquer ici pour avoir un aperçu de la zone ! </b></a>`).openPopup();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Custom styling for Geiranger popup content */

.geiranger-popup-content {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Everything works as expected and I have to say that I'm quite happy with the rendering. However by looking at the different topics on Stackoverflow I discovered the possibility of displaying Google Street View by clicking on the map. This feature is really cool, but I would like to limit the option of adding a Street View marker only on the itinerary of my road trip.
Could someone help me out with that please ?

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and came to these conclusions.Can you try. Sorry for my previous comment.

Add This scripts:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.icon.glyph@0.2.0/Leaflet.Icon.Glyph.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
```

and Rewrite Route Code:

```
var _waypoints= roadTripCoordinates.map(coord => L.latLng(coord[0], coord[1]))
    // Use Leaflet Routing Machine with Mapbox Routing plugin to get and display the route
    var control = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: _waypoints,
      router: L.Routing.mapbox('MAP_BOX_KEY'),
      draggableWaypoints: false,
      addWaypoints: false,
      plan: L.Routing.plan(_waypoints, {
        createMarker: function(i, wp) {
          return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
            draggable: true,
            icon: L.icon.glyph({ glyph: String.fromCharCode(65 + i) })
          });
        },
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
        routeWhileDragging: true
          }),
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [{
          color: 'brown',
          opacity: 0.7,
          weight: 2
        }]
      }
    }).addTo(map);

L.Routing.errorControl(control).addTo(map);
```